TCL - A condition for an item while appending items to a list
I have this list
set csv [list]
lappend csv [list \
a \
b \
c \
[expr {[cfg::get enable_all_columns]
? {
d
}
: {}
}]  \
e \
f \
g]

I need to add element d only if enable_all_columns is 1. The problem is that with this approach if it is 0, it returns something empty which creates a new column in csv raport.
That lappend to output this list {a b c d e f g}
I tried to break the lappend to put the condition and then add the last ones, but this results in this {a b c} d e f g
I also tried linsert but it did the same
set csv [list]

lappend csv [list \
a       \
b]

set csv [linsert $csv 1 x]

puts "$csv"


I would do it this way:
set csv {a b c e f g}
if {[cfg::get enable_all_columns]} {
    set csv [linsert $csv 3 d]
}


Expansion  allows you to make something that disappears when empty.
set csv [list]
lappend csv [list a b c {*}[if {[cfg::get enable_all_columns]} {
    list d
}] e f g]


I prefer if to expr for this sort of thing, unless the values are numeric.
